# UI Router - do not resolve without changing state

Tags: angular-ui-router

I defined state that has some parameters in URL. I'm also using resolve feature. When I'm changing some of these parameters via

```
$state.go('.', {...parameters...}, {notify:false, reload: false})
```

dependencies defined in state configuration are resolved again, causing browser to create unnecessary HTTP requests to server. It's not a behavior I would expect, since I'm not changing state (or I'm changing it to the same state, but with flag reload set to false).

How can I solve this and change visible URL via UI Router without causing unnecessary resolves?

Answer (score 0):

I also looking for answer on this question